# NextJS dynamic tags by the database entity

Tags: next.js, seo, server-side-rendering

I have an app in NextJS and when I'm sending a link to specific page I get:

which is the favicon and title and description tags.

[image]

but I want to be able to embed links in WhatsApp/ Slack etc... with dynamic titles and descriptions from the data related to a specific link

The link looks like this:
{hostname}/report/{id}

for each Id I need different name + description

I tried to move everything to SSR but and setting the Head with the tags, and still doesn't worked...

thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code you have for the meta tags you're adding to `head`?

Comment: @juliomalves

`<Head>
        <title>{meta.title}</title>
        <meta name="title" content={meta.title} />
        <meta name="description" content={meta.description} />
        <meta property="og:url" content="https://app.thequack.io" />
        <meta property="og:title" content={meta.title} />
        <meta property="og:description" content={meta.description} />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="Quack report" />
      </Head>`
the meta is coming from the getServerSideProps

Comment: Could you please add the component's code properly formatted to the question? Also, please add the `getServerSideProps` code as well.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `getInitialProps` instead of `getServerSideProps`. It will show you dynamic title and description as per API response.

> `getInitialProps` enables server-side rendering in a page and allows you to do **initial data population**, it means sending the page with the data already populated from the server. This is especially useful for **SEO**.

You can find this in [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props)